# Как узнать Bundle ID своего приложения?

Tags: android, google-play

Как узнать Bundle ID своего приложения? Могу ли я его узнать, если ещё не выложил в Google Play?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Bundle ID* в iOS и в Android – это *Package Name*, то что указано в манифесте. Для получения в рантайме, есть метод `Context.getPackageName()`.

Comment: если у меня две библиотеки, одна отвечает за анимацию, вторая содержит само приложение, то package name мне следует указывать с самим приложением?

Comment: Да, в модуле приложения, он попадет в манфест финального APK.